# Embedding a python interpreter to c++

Tags: c++, python, user-interface, integration, interpreter

You'll have to forgive me if this question has been answered, but I haven't been able to find anything that specifically talks about what I need.

I am attempting to embed a python interpreter into a GUI written in C++.  To describe it a bit more fully, I have a series of images that will be displayed in a window.  These images will be streamed from a server, along with various information about the images and how they compare to each other.  The GUI will also have a large text area at the bottom with a prompt (like the '>>>' prompt in the python CLI) that the user can type valid python code into, then the app executes that code based on the information it has on the image currently being displayed.

For example, if the image is stored in a struct that contains height and width information (`image->height` and `image->width`), and I have written in Python a class that interfaces with the data currently displayed (everything would do what it looks like it should do), I need to be able to execute the following and get the output:

```
>>> from image import image #custom module and class for interfacing with my GUI
>>> img = image.get_current_image() #returns a Python object relating to the image currently displayed
>>> img.width
800
>>>img.height
600
>>> img.aspect_ratio()
4:3
```

I am aware of a few methods of accessing c++ classes from python code, such as [Boost Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/python/doc/).  What I am not sure how to do is a create the interpreter inside a C++ GUI.  The issue is the python and C++ must communicate with each other in realtime, and must share memory.  For example, the python module may contain a `to_grayscale()` function that converts the image to grayscale, which would require that the python module retireve the image from C++, convert it, and send it back to be rerendered.

Just to make it clear, I don't need help doing that conversion or anything like that.  Just how do I integrate the interpreter with C++?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot find anything specific in your requirements – it seems to be straight-forward interpreter embedding.  The documentation is at [Embedding Python in Another Application](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html).  I don't think we can reasonably *answer* this question, except for providing this link.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That seems to be a valid answer in the spirit of SO.  Perhaps it's not always obvious how simple the answer to that question is.  In hindsight, I regret voting to close.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That's a pretty darn useful link.  I guess I assumed that python/C++ wouldn't have this kind of thing built right in like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding Python into C++ application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971928/embedding-python-into-c-application)

Comment: To clarify, I did not vote to close as "not a real question", but simply as duplicate. It has been answered before, see the link above.

Comment: @DrewDormann: It is SO policy that an [answers should contain more information than merely a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259), and this would have been the only bit of information in my answer.